# How do contact forces change with distance?

Tags: forces, atomic-physics

Typically, two bodies don't exert a force on each other when separated, but if they go in contact with each other, that is, get sufficiently close, contact forces arise. Consider the case I press my hand on the wall. Of which order is the distance between the atoms of my hand and those of the wall? How much closer will they be if I, say, increase the force by a factor of 2? In other words, how does the force between my hand and the wall change as a function of distance? My first guess would be that if the force is of electromagnetic origin, then perhaps it should be proportional to $1/r^2$, but this doesn't seem correct, as there are certainly many factors at play.

Answer (score 0):

The order of magnitude between force and distance between atoms or molecules can be grasped by knowing [how water compresses with pressure](https://www.britannica.com/science/seawater/Density-of-seawater-and-pressure).

The water density in the oceans increases only $2$% from the surface to $4 $km, the average sea depth. That corresponds to a decrease of $0.6$% in the average molecular distance. But the pressure increases from $1$ bar to $400$ bar. As the compressibility is very small, the cross area can be taken as the same, meaning that the force increases $400$ times for a decrease of only $0.6$% in the distance between molecules.

What happens with our body, made mainly by water should be similar. The distance between our hand and the wall should be shortened by the same rate when increasing the force.

Modelling a force $F = \frac{k}{r^x}$, $x$ is much greater than $2$.